# Proper implementation for a 2 type parameters Functor in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, functional-programming

I saw this question several times on SO, but no matter how hard I try, I can't make the following code compile. The goal is to implement an `Functor` implementation for a simpler `Reader` (the code is [here](https://github.com/FrancisToth/FP)):

```
  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def fmap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
  }

  implicit class FunctorOps[F[_]: Functor, A](self: F[A]) {
    def fmap[B](f: A => B): F[B] = implicitly[Functor[F]].fmap(self)(f)
  }

  case class Reader[A, B](run: A => B)
  type ReaderF[X] = ({ type L[A] = Reader[X, A] })

  implicit def readerFunctors[E]: Functor[ReaderF[E]#L] = 
    new Functor[ReaderF[E]#L] {
       override def fmap[A, B](fa: Reader[E, A])(f: A => B): Reader[E, B] = 
          Reader(e => f(fa.run(e)))
    }

  val foo = Reader[String, Int](_ => 42)

  foo.fmap(_ + 1) // does not compile
```

I tried to bypass the implicit mechanism with the following:

```
FunctorOps(foo).fmap(_ + 1)
```

but this outputs the following compilation error:

```
Error:(82, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : com.fp.Scratchpad.Reader[String,Int]
 required: ?F[?A]
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](self: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
 and method Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](self: A)Ensuring[A]
 are possible conversion functions from com.fp.Scratchpad.Reader[String,Int] to ?F[?A]
  FunctorOps(foo).fmap(_ + 1)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

Just to make sure my FunctorOps is right, I created a functor instance for `Id`:

```
case class Id[A](value: A)
implicit val idF: Functor[Id] = new Functor[Id] {
  override def fmap[A, B](fa: Id[A])(f: A => B): Id[B] = Id(f(fa.value))
}

val id = Id(42)
id.fmap(_ + 1) // compiles
```

So the problem does not come from the `FunctorOps` implicit class. I suspect Scala to have a real hard time with type lambdas...

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to simplify the problem but without success:

```
  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def map[A, B](x: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
  }

  implicit class Ops[F[_], A](fa: F[A])(implicit F: Functor[F]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = F.map(fa)(f)
  }

  type FF[A] = ({ type F[B] = A => B })

  implicit def ff[E]: Functor[FF[E]#F] = new Functor[FF[E]#F] {
    override def map[A, B](x: E => A)(f: A => B): E => B = e => f(x(e))
  }

  val f: String => Int = _ => 42

  val value: Functor[FF[String]#F] = ff[String]
  val ops = new Ops[FF[String]#F, Int](f)(value)

  // These compile
  ops.map(_ + 1)("")
  value.map(f)(_ + 1)("")

  // This not
  f.map(_ + 1)
```

Comment: What is your Scala version? The first one compiles in https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gpRKdKjNS4KLTAq7Zwptsw. I was actually surprised it seems to work in older versions too, I assumed you need 2.12 or 2.11.11+.

Comment: I've just checked and Scala version is 2.12.8. Tried to compile with IDEA and sbt :(

Comment: Are you running this in a Worksheet?

Comment: No, and I also tried to compile this raw sbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I think that, to have this working, you need to enable some extra options for the compiler in `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-Ypartial-unification",
      "-language:postfixOps",
      "-language:higherKinds",
      "-deprecation",
      "-encoding", "UTF-8",
      "-feature",      
      "-unchecked"
    )
```

More info on the *partial unification* flag and what it solves [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
Are you running your code through Worksheet or a Scratch in IDEA? I have noticed that sometimes, especially in these kind of functional programming tasks where there is type inference, implicit resolution and higher kinded type "magic", IDEA's REPLs are not up to the task (but I am not sure why).

This said, I tried to run the following on IDEA:

```
object TestApp extends App{
  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def fmap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
  }

  implicit class FunctorOps[F[_]: Functor, A](self: F[A]) {
    def fmap[B](f: A => B): F[B] = implicitly[Functor[F]].fmap(self)(f)
  }

  case class Reader[A, B](run: A => B)
  type ReaderF[X] = ({ type L[A] = Reader[X, A] })

  implicit def readerFunctors[E]: Functor[ReaderF[E]#L] =
    new Functor[ReaderF[E]#L] {
      override def fmap[A, B](fa: Reader[E, A])(f: A => B): Reader[E, B] =
        Reader(e => f(fa.run(e)))
    }

  val foo: Reader[String, Int] = Reader[String, Int](s => s.length)

  val i = foo.fmap(_ + 1)

  println(i.run("Test"))
  println(i.run("Hello World"))
}
```

And it works fine, printing `5` and `12`. Also, as someone else mentioned, your code works on Scastie, which is another syntom of IDEA's acting up.

One final note: you probably already know this, but you can avoid all that type-lambda ugliness using the [kind-projector compiler plugin](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/12/05/type-lambdas.html).

Long story short, drop the `ReaderF[X]` type alias, and make your functor instance look like this:

```
implicit def readerFunctors[X]: Functor[Reader[X,?]] =
    new Functor[Reader[X,?]] {
      override def fmap[B, C](fa: Reader[X,B])(f: B => C): Reader[X,C] =
        Reader(e => f(fa.run(e)))
    }
```

Which is more readable IMHO.

Comment: I copy pasted the code on IDEA, and it does not even compile :( Same on sbt. I am using scala 2.12.8 and sbt 1.2.8. I also tried to run this (without the `TestApp`) in the standard REPL and still no success. What versions do you use?

Comment: scalac also found an error at `val i = foo.fmap(_ + 1)`

Comment: ....this is very strange. I use a normal configuration, Scala 2.12.8, nothing fancy or strange...

Comment: But either way, I think it's clear now that, whatever the problem is, it's not in the code but in your environment. Which is kind of good news I guess :)

Comment: I am still not sure about this to be honest. Could you please give me the version of sbt/scala you are using?

Comment: 2.12.8, 1.2.8. But again, if it works on Scastie, you know it probably has nothing to do with the code itself.

Comment: My workmates are not able to run the code either, this is really weird.

Comment: ah, wait I might have an idea! What scalacOptions are you using in your build?

Comment: I've just added a github link to the question

Comment: edited, try adding that in `build.sbt` and see if it fixes it. I suspect the most important thing is the `-Ypartial-unification` bit...

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I still have to understand how this could be done, but thank you anyway! UPD: here's the link: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/partial-unification.html